# Laravel variable cache

Tags: php, laravel

I need to cache the results from Steam API parsing. And so the cached result lasts 15 minutes. I have a code:

```
public function load()
    {
        if (Auth::guest()) return response()->json(['success' => false, 'msg' => 'You need login!']);

        $inventory = $this->getInventory(file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/' . $this->user->steamid64 . '/570/2?l=russian&count=5000', true));

        if (!$inventory) {
            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'msg' => 'Error']);
        }

        $items = [];

        $items_with_prices = json_decode(\Storage::get('prices.txt'));

        $items_with_prices_by_key = [];

        foreach ($items_with_prices->items as $item_price_key => $item_price_data) {
            $items_with_prices_by_key[$item_price_key] = $item_price_data->price;
        }

        foreach ($inventory['rgInventory'] as $info) {
            $item = $inventory['rgDescriptions'][$info['classid'] . '_' . $info['instanceid']];
            if ($item['tradable'] == 0) continue;

            $price = 0;//InventoryController::getItemPrice($item['market_hash_name']);
            if (array_key_exists($item['market_hash_name'], $items_with_prices_by_key)) {
                $price = $items_with_prices_by_key[$item['market_hash_name']];
            }
            if (!$price) continue;

            if ($price < 1) $price = 0.64;

            $type = $this->getType($item['type']);

            $items[] = [
                'id' => $info['id'],
                'classid' => $item['icon_url'],
                'price' => round($price, 2),
                'type' => $type
            ];
        }

        usort($items, function($a, $b){
            return ($b['price'] - $a['price']);
        });

        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'items' => $items]);
    }
```

This code only works when a site user clicks on the "show my items" button and a request is sent to the list of user items in Steam Dota 2. Now if click constantly to get a list of items, Steam can block the server’s IP address for 24 hours. As I understand it, I need to throw the result of a `$inventory` variable into the cache. I create database table `cache` with fields `id`, `user_id`, `items`, `date`.

How can I now cache the result from a `$inventory` variable of 15 minutes?

Comment: why don't you just add the creation time along with database that you have created and every time check if the difference is greater than 15 min then fetch from api else fetch from db.

Comment: why are you deleted the old question? I gave you a valid logic to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is basic caching in laravel

```php
$rememberTimeInSeconds = 3600;
$cachedResult = Cache::remember('name_of_your_cache', $rememberTimeInSeconds, function(){

// It can be any logic I just showing a simple query.
$users = User::all();

return $users;

});
```